# Command to re-calibrate magnetic sensor

Tags: command-line

Is there any command through which I can reset the magnetic sensor in an Android device?

I tried `echo 1 > /sys/class/sensors/proximity_sensor/prox_cal` as suggested [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2353972) but it's not working.

Are these commands handset dependent?

I am trying this code:

```
Process process ;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo 1 > /sys/class/sensors/proximity_sensor/prox_cal");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Executing ADB Command");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Some error while executing ADB Command");
    }
```

It's always going in the catch block. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: From https://f-droid.org you can download the source for an app `Sensor Readout` to check if and how it can be done.

Comment: I checked it out. The app only `register` and `unregister` the listener. I want to force re calibrate the sensors.

Comment: What type of sensor has your device anyway?

Comment: `Sensors:Accelerometer, gyro, proximity, compass` Moto G,2nd Gen. Took the info from gsmarena.

Comment: Proximity hasn't that much to do with magnetic. Do you have other files ending with `_cal` beyond `sensors`? I found this to do it manually: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1778131

Comment: I don't want to this manually, as it creates a user dependency. In my app I need the magnetic data to find the location, it works correctly, but sometimes the data goes haywire. So in order to correct that, I wanted to re calibrate the sensor at some time intervals. And to do the recalibration on a device, I need to pass some the command which will do that.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if it's possible to calibrate sensor system-wide. Most apps will ask user to do calibration *inside the app* and store the deviation as the base value. Aside of that, I don't have any `_cal` files on that `/sensors` folder on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, so it's understandable that the code will go into `catch-block`.